# How I can change the text of a single label from a string array vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, loops, timer, label, backgroundworker

so I want to display a string array in a single label that change the contents with a period of time ,
I ve tried every thing the timer, the background worker every thing   , the problem when I use a loop inset a timer the interval in the start should be so long if the array items was so many  so I tried the background worker but it not works
this is the code :

```
 Dim array() As String = {"so", "nb", "de", "rty", "dcds"}
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False

End Sub




 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim delay As Integer = 2000
    Dim interval As Integer = 100
    Dim elapsed As Integer = 0
    Dim pos As Integer = array.Length

    While Not worker.CancellationPending
        If (elapsed >= delay) Then
            worker.ReportProgress(pos)
            ' change label text in the Progress event handler
            pos = (pos + 1)
            elapsed = 0
            If (pos = array.Length) Then
                Exit While
            End If

        End If

        Thread.Sleep(interval)

    End While
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim j As Integer
    For j = 0 To array.Length
        Label1.Text = array(j)

    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: _but it not works_ - What you mean? Can you explain or display what value should be displayed in Label and how repeatedly?

Comment: Why you passing `pos` variable into `ReportProgress`? You are not using it there.

Comment: Do you want to display all values of array in the label one after another with 2 seconds delay?

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is overwriting the .Text property of the lable on each iteration. You will also get an Index Out of Range exception because the indexes of an array are zero based. The highest index will be 1 less than the .Length.

```
Private arStr() As String = {"so", "nb", "de", "rty", "dcds"}

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim LabelText = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, arStr)
    Label1.Text = LabelText
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```
Private arStr() As String = {"so", "nb", "de", "rty", "dcds"}

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static index As Integer
    If index < arStr.Length Then
        Label1.Text &= arStr(index) & Environment.NewLine
        index += 1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you  but it display it one time  I mean that label  the label should display the data  one after one and repeatedly

Answer (score 0):

With asynchronous approach you can display array values one after another without BackgroundWorker and explicitly created Timer.

```
Private _values As New String() From {"so", "nb", "de", "rty", "dcds"}

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each value In _values
        await Task.Delay(2000)
    Next
End Sub
```

With asynchronous approach you can prevent button click before all values are displayed in the simple way as you would do in synchronous code.

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim button = DirectCast(sender, Button);
    button.Enabled = False

    For Each value In _values
        await Task.Delay(2000)
    Next

    button.Enabled = True
End Sub
```